# Can a device be TLS compliant without RSA?

Tags: tls, rsa

Let's consider an embedded device which supports ECC and some symmetric cryptographic primitives but not the RSA algorithm.

Can it be TLS compliant? I think that if the device and the server share a cipher suite which has nothing to do with RSA, then there is no problem.

The [RFC 5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-9) makes me doubtful because of this section:

> 9. Mandatory Cipher Suites
>
> In the absence of an application profile standard specifying otherwise,
> a TLS-compliant application MUST implement the cipher suite
> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (see Appendix A.5 for the definition).

So what should I conclude?

Comment: I wonder what's going to happen when the chosen SHA hash (I think it's SHA-256 but don't quote me on this) is found to be too weak. AES128 may hold forever but we've had bad luck on hashes.

Comment: @Joshua: If you believe AES is secure then then can't you just encrypt it with some portion of itself as the key to simulate a hash and then XOR its chunks together to turn it into something small? In fact it makes me wonder why people don't do that...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This clearly says "In the absence of an application profile standard specifying otherwise". Which means if you write a TLS stack and expect arbitrary TLS implementations to connect then you must implement the given cipher as the minimal common cipher. If instead you need the TLS stack only for a specific application and define the ciphers used by the application as ECC only then you don't need to implement this specific cipher.